# Parsing resources

Tags: parsing

Does anyone know any resources (books/websites/whatever) related to parsing. I'm not so much interested in specific technologies such as yacc, XML or regular expressions, but something more general about best practices, stream vs. pull, error reporting and recovery, gotchas to look out for etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a nice book on parsing techniques [Parsing Techniques, a Practical Guige](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~dick/PTAPG.html). You should be able to find some interesting bits. There is complete chapter on error handling.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you meant, but a very good, and slightly relevant, book;
[Data Crunching: Solve Everyday Problems using Java, Python, and More](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/gwd/data-crunching)